# Problems with PayPal IPN variables

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, sandbox, paypal-sandbox

Im using PayPal as main payment system, so I decided to add it inside my custom built script, however I have problems with IPN variables because when I try to echo any of those variables for example

```
$item_number
$txn_id
```

I get nothing from above variables. Everything is passed correctly to PayPal and the payment is received, but when user is redirected to my "Thank you" page where I need to grab that $item_number item number in order to update the database nothing is passed. Im doing testings using Sandbox for now.

This is the url values when redirected to my website:

```
http://example.com/thankyou.php?tx=8LT93279034418017&st=Completed&amt=20%2e00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=29
```

this is my IPN code:

```
<?php
// STEP 1: Read POST data

// reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
// issues with array data in POST
// reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $custom_value = $_POST['custom'];
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
?>
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing PDT and IPN.  PDT is what would send data back to your return URL.  IPN happens completely separate from your checkout flow and isn't something anybody sees on screen, so echoing data wouldn't be seen by anybody.

IPN is indeed the recommended way to handle database updates, email notifications, etc. because even with Auto-Return enabled there is no guarantee users would make it back to your ReturnURL (when using Payments Standard), in which case the code would never run for those orders.

It looks like you just pulled the IPN sample from PayPal, so you need to customize it to suit your needs, and again, keep in mind it's not anything you'll see on screen.  You'll need to check PayPal's IPN History and your web server logs to see if it's getting hit and if any errors may be happening.

Of course, you'll need to make sure you have IPN configured in your PayPal profile, too, or that you've set notify_url in your payment code.

So your thank you page would really be nothing more than that, and then IPN would handle updating the db and notifying the user about anything they need to know.